# How to change html of a jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my function I am calling method passing `$obj` as a parameter in the function. I have defined `currsel` object, now in the method its showing me `$obj.currsel.html()` is not a function.  I am sharing my code below.

```
$(document).on('change','.ui-modulelist1',function(e){
    var $targetSel =coreFrameWork.frModuleContId;
    var $thisVal= $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    var loadUrl = '../ux_framework_New/_'+$thisVal+'/index.html';
    commonFramework.initLoad({'url':loadUrl, 'currSel':$targetSel, 'mode':'autoload'});
            });

var commonFramework ={

    initLoad:function($obj){
                $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: $obj.url,
                        dataType: "html",
                        cache:false,
                        async:false,
                        beforeSend: function(xhr){
                            xhr.withCredentials = false;
                        },
                        success: function(html) {
                            $obj.currSel.html(html);
                            $obj.currSel.attr(projCommonAttr.autoloadAttr,'loaded');
                        commonFramework.contentSpecific({'currSel':$obj.currSel,'mode':$obj.mode});
                        },
                        error: function(qXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

                        }           

                });
        },
```

Comment: Is this `coreFrameWork.frModuleContId` an ID or a element node?

Comment: ya wouldn't it be `var $targetSel = $('#' + coreFrameWork.frModuleContId)`

Answer (score 0):

```
url: $obj.url,
```

This parameter needs to be a string. If you want a dynamic url from your obj variable do this:

```
url: $obj+".php", // .php or whatever the file type is of the page you're requesting
```

Comment: people denote jQuery object varibles with `$`, its normal so they know this varible is a jQuery object. `var $div = $('#myDiv');`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing an example url.  What is coreFrameWork.frModuleContId?  Try logging it in your console.  I'm guessing you need to do

```
var $targetSel = $(coreFrameWork.frModuleContId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this:

```
var $targetSel =coreFrameWork.frModuleContId;
```

a jQuery object?

The function html() belongs to jQuery, so if your object is not a jQuery one, it won't find that method.

I don't exactly know what that variable is, but you can try by wrapping it into a jQuery object:

```
var $targetSel = jQuery(coreFrameWork.frModuleContId);
```

Also, it is not a good practice to use names beginning with $ to name simple js objects (those names are often used to name variables representing jQuery objects or so).

Hope this helps you.

Regards,

Marcelo